# How to merge two different sum of squared errors?

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, linear-algebra

Given two datasets $ U \in R$ and $P \in R$. $n_1$ and $n_2$ are respectively the number of points contained in U and P. The sum of squared errors of U and P are as follow:

$$ SSE_U=\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}||u_i-\bar u||^2 \\ SSE_P=\sum_{i=1}^{n_2} ||p_i-\bar p||^2$$

Now, given a dataset $V=U \bigcup P$, the mean of V is as follows:
$$ \bar v = \frac{ n1*\bar u + n2 * \bar p}{n1 + n2}  $$

The points in U and P are unique and the points in V are also unique. So we have $n_3 = n_1 + n_2$ with $n_3$ the number of points contained in V.

My question is how to compute the SSE of the dataset V using only the SSE and the mean of the datasets U and P.

Comment: What are $k_1,k_2$ and how so you use $j$ indices? Also, it should be SST instead of SSE, and if you take the union of two sets, you may drop duplicate entries in which you can’t use the formula for the mean you quote.

Comment: @gunes I updated my post. $k_1$ and $k_2$ are respectively the number of the clusters of U and P with $k_1 \ne k_2$. The indices j loop the clusters of U and P cluster by cluster. The points of U and P are unique and the points resulting from the union of U and P are unique. We have $n_3=n_1+n_2$ with $n_3$ the number of points of V.

Comment: So, the summand doesn’t use index $j$?

Comment: @gunes you're right, I forgot to add the indice j so that we have $\bar u_j$ and $\bar p_j$ . I updated the post. I simplified the problem because each dataset has only one cluster, that to say, itself. There are no longer the indices j.

Comment: @gunes have you any idea about the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are trying to find the following quantity:
$$\begin{align}S_v&=\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} ||u_i-\bar{v}||^2}_{S_{uv}}+\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n_2}||p_i-\bar{v}||^2}_{S_{pv}}\end{align}$$
Let's focus on the first term:
$$\begin{align}S_{uv}&=\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}||u_i-\bar{v}||^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}||(u_i-\bar{u})+(\bar{u}-\bar{v})||^2\\&=\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}||u_i-\bar{u}||^2}_{S_u}+2\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}(u_i-\bar{u})^T\right)}_{0}(\bar{u}-\bar{v})+n_1||\bar{u}-\bar{v}||^2\\&=S_u+n_1||\bar{u}-\bar{v}||^2\end{align}$$

So, the total quantity becomes
$$S_v=S_u+S_p+n_1||\bar{u}-\bar{v}||^2+n_2||\bar{p}-\bar{v}||^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is really helpful. I have a question about $S_{uv}$, why $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n_1} (u_i-\bar u)^T = 0$$

Comment: Ignoring the transpose, $$\sum (u_i-\bar{u}) = \sum u_i - \sum \bar{u} = \bar{u}n_1-\bar{u}n_1=0$$

Comment: Is this solution true for whatever the dimension of the points?

Comment: Yes, that's why I used the norm notation; otherwise it'd be absolute value.

Comment: Thank you very much!